# WordPress paginate_links() Customization

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress paginate_links() function, which is working, however I'd like to slightly later the html that is output.
Heres whats currently being displayed:

```
<a class="prev page-numbers" href="">« Previous</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href=''>1</a>
<span class='page-numbers current'>2</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href=''>3</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href=''>4</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href=''>5</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="">Next »</a>
```

The php:

```
<?php

$pages = array(

'show_all' => true,
'prev_text' => __('« Previous'),
'next_text' => __('Next »'),
 );

 echo paginate_links($pages);

?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the page number links wrapped inside of a div like so:

```
<a class="prev page-numbers" href="">« Previous</a>
 <div class="center-page-numbers"><!--- Div Wrap --->
  <a class='page-numbers' href=''>1</a>
  <span class='page-numbers current'>2</span>
  <a class='page-numbers' href=''>3</a>
  <a class='page-numbers' href=''>4</a>
  <a class='page-numbers' href=''>5</a>
 </div><!--- Div Wrap --->
<a class="next page-numbers" href="">Next »</a>
```

This way I can center the page numbers using margin: 0 auto;
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your data with type = array. You will get an array of the links and you can do the html markup yourself.

```
    $pages = array(
    'type' => 'array'

     );

     $links = paginate_links($pages);

     foreach($links as $link){
        // Render the HTML here
     }
```